# Checking for dead links locally in a static website (using wget?)

Tags: python, hyperlink, http-status-code-404, wget

A very nice tool to check for dead links (e.g. links pointing to 404 errors) is [`wget --spider`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-find-broken-links-on-your-website-using-wget-on-debian-7). However, I have a slightly different use-case where I generate a static website, and want to check for broken links before uploading. More precisely, I want to check both:

- Relative links like `<a href="some/file.pdf">file.pdf</a>`
- Absolute links, most likely to external sites like `<a href="http://example.com">example</a>`.

I tried `wget --spyder --force-html -i file-to-check.html`, which reads the local file, considers it as HTML and follows each links. Unfortunately, it can't deal with relative links within the local HTML file (errors out with `Cannot resolve incomplete link some/file.pdf`). I tried using `file://` but `wget` does not support it.

Currently, I have a hack based on running a local webserver throught `python3 http.serve` and checking the local files through HTTP:

```
python3 -m http.server &
pid=$! 
sleep .5
error=0
wget --spider -nd -nv -H -r -l 1 http://localhost:8000/index.html || error=$? 
kill $pid
wait $pid
exit $error
```

I'm not really happy with this for several reasons:

- I need this `sleep .5` to wait for the webserver to be ready. Without it, the script fails, but I can't guarantee that 0.5 seconds will be enough. I'd prefer having a way to start the `wget` command when the server is ready.
- Conversely, this `kill $pid` feels ugly.

Ideally, `python3 -m http.server` would have an option to run a command when the server is ready and would shutdown itself after the command is completed. That sounds doable by writing a bit of Python, but I was wondering whether a cleaner solution exists.

Did I miss anything? Is there a better solution? I'm mentioning `wget` in my question because it does almost what I want, but using `wget` is not a requirement for me (nor is `python -m http.server`). I just need to have something easy to run and automate on Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I think you are running in the right direction. I would use `wget` and `python` as they are two readily available options on many systems. And the good part is that it gets the job done for you. Now what you want is to listen for `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0` from the `stdout` of that process.

So I would start the process using something like below

```
python3 -u -m http.server > ./myserver.log &
```

Note the `-u` I have used here for unbuffered output, this is really important

Now next is waiting for this text to appear in `myserver.log`

```
timeout 10 awk '/Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0/{print; exit}' <(tail -f ./myserver.log)
```

So `10` seconds is your maximum wait time here. And rest is self-explanatory. Next about your `kill $pid`. I don't think it is a problem, but if you want it to be more like the way a user does it then I would change it to

```
kill -s SIGINT $pid
```

This will be equivalent to you processing `CTRL+C` after launching the program. Also I would handle the `SIGINT` my bash script as well using something like below

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313644/execute-command-or-function-when-sigint-or-sigterm-is-send-to-the-parent-script/313648

The above basically adds below to top of the bash script to handle you killing the script using `CTRL+C` or external kill signal

```
#!/bin/bash
exit_script() {
    echo "Printing something special!"
    echo "Maybe executing other commands!"
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM # clear the trap
    kill -- -$$ # Sends SIGTERM to child/sub processes
}

trap exit_script SIGINT SIGTERM
```

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution, but short of something simpler, this is clean and effective. Thanks. I'm leaving the answer unaccepted for a while in case someone can find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Tarun Lalwani's answer is correct, and following the advices given there one can write a clean and short shell script (relying on Python and awk). Another solution is to write the script completely in Python, giving a slightly more verbose but arguably cleaner script. The server can be launched in a thread, then the command to check the website is executed, and finally the server is shut down. We don't need to parse the textual output nor to send a signal to an external process anymore. The key parts of the script are therefore:

```
def start_server(port,
                 server_class=HTTPServer,
                 handler_class=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
    thread.start()
    return httpd

def main(cmd, port):
    httpd = start_server(port)
    status = subprocess.call(cmd)
    httpd.shutdown()
    sys.exit(status)
```

I wrote a slightly more advanced script (with a bit of command-line option parsing on top of this) and published it as: https://gitlab.com/moy/check-links